# How does the underscore forward movement work? _f

Tags: cursor-motions, movement

I was recently watching a more advanced vim tutorial on youtube. One of the commands used was `_f`. This was actually just part of a longer macro being demonstrated and the underscore wasn't commented on.

Using the letter **e** as an example: I tried it on a long line of text and there is indeed a difference between `fe` and `_fe` but I can't understand what is happening. `_fe` doesn't go to the first, second, or last occurrence of **e** on the line.

What is `_f` doing? Bonus points for why is it doing it!

**EDIT to add example**

The following is a single line of random text. With my curser at the beginning of the line `fe` arrives at the first e, which I have highlighted and demarcated.

2:5 Now no shrub of th`**e**` field had yet grown on the earth, and no plant of the field had yet sprouted, for the Lord God had not caused it to rain on the earth, and there was no man to cultivate the ground. 2:6 Springs would well up from the earth and water the whole surface of the ground. 2:7 The Lord God formed the man from the soil of the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living being.

However if I use `_fe` it skips over the first two instances of **e** and lands in the third instance.

2:5 Now no shrub of th**e** fi**e**ld had y`**e**`t grown on the earth, and no plant of the field had yet sprouted, for the Lord God had not caused ...

I have tried it with other letters, with the similar result of not hitting the first occurrence of that letter.

Comment: Something is off.  When I start vim with `vim -u NONE` and put your paragraph in (as a single long line) as the only line in a document, wherever I start the cursor off at `_fe` takes me to the first **e**.  Can you confirm that skipping to the third **e** is the case when you start with `-u NONE`?

Comment: Using `-u NONE` yields the expected result for `_fe`. I assume that means there is something in my `.vimrc` file causing the issue.

Comment: Might be helpful: [how do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file)

Comment: It sounds like something is mapping `_` (or `_f`). Try `:verbose map _` to get an idea of where that mapping might be.

Comment: Ugh. I have `nnoremap _ 3` on line 185 of my `.vimrc. (The reason for this is that I use vim for both Thai and English and when in the Thai keyboard the "3" key produces an underscore. I've fixed the mapping using `Leader` and we are good to go until the next conflict!)
`

Comment: Note: I rolled back the edit to add "Solved" to the question title. We typically don't do that at Stack Exchange. You already accepted one answer, so that's signal enough that your question has been acceptably answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_fe` should go to the first occurrence of **e** on that line.  Can you give an example of where it doesn't?

From `:h _`:

```
_  <underscore>         [count] - 1 lines downward, on the first non-blank
                        character linewise.
```

In other words, `_` without a count moves to the first non-blank character of the current line, then `fe` goes to the first instance of **e**.

Comment: Similar to `0fe` or `^fe`, which I think are clearer

Comment: Good point @DBenKnoble. I have to confess I’ve never used `_`, not least because it’s more effort to type than `0`.